# HyperV host UUID is not updated in VMM

Tags: hyper-v, scvmm

I made some changes to HyperV host SMBIOS that caused host UUID change.

The problem that in VMM I still see old host UUID (in host properties and in Get-SCVMHost). I tried to restart VMM service and VMM agent, I tried to refresh host and cluster - UUID still wrong.

Is there  any way to re-sync VMM with the host so host UUID will be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is to change the value in Table "**dbo.tbl_PMM_PhysicalMachine**" of DB "**VirtualManagerDB**":

[image]

Comment: I found that it also helps to remove host from VMM and add it again.